# XRDP "Password failed, error - problem connecting"

Tags: connection, xrdp

I did a new Ubuntu 16.04 install, followed all necessary instructions to run and setup XRDP + Xfce4. When I try to connect, I get:

```
connecting to sesman IP 127.0.0.1 port 3350
sesman connect ok
sending login info to session manager, please wait... 
xrdp_mm_process_login_response:login successful for display started connecting

connecting to 127.0.0.1 5910 
tcp connected security level is 2 (1= none, 2 = standard) 
**password failed error-problem connecting**
```

I am more than sure that there is no issue with password as I login on the console with the same password. 
on the thread
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/xrdp-password-failed-error-problem-connecting-4175583547/

I followed suggested fix, no way, event able to have any details

So what I am missing to be able to RDP this machine

I even followed couple of other threads talking about Locke x11 locked file but nothing helped.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue while connecting through xrdp.

**There is a problem with the latest xrdp update**.
More info [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xrdp/+bug/1811122).

Reverting to the previous version solves the issue:

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp=0.6.1-2
```

Comment: Exact, I downgraded, I can RDP to ubuntu. In the link provided, it is mentioned that whenever there is an update, xrdp goes back to the new bugged version, how can this be stoped?